# How to use PIL in django models

Tags: django, model, resize, python-imaging-library, imagefield

I like to resize an uploaded image(ImageField) before finally storing, I heard that python has an image library called PIL and I would like to use it do that task but I'm not sure on how to start.

Any suggestions on how to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can override model's save function where you can open file and resize it (not recommended, as it will resize it each time you save a model), you an resize after file upload (e.g. before/during form.save())

but IMHO a far better solution is to use a dedicated app for this, my favourite is [sorl-thumbnails](https://github.com/sorl/sorl-thumbnail)

Comment: Thanks, I'll look on sorl-thumbnails

Answer (score 0):

I've just found out on how to do it but is there a way to simplify it? I'm new in python and django so I'm not sure if this is the proper way to do it.

below is my code:

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_delete, pre_save

def on_save_image(sender, **kwargs):
    import PIL
    obj = kwargs['instance']
    if obj.file:
        try:
            original = sender.objects.get(pk = obj.pk)
            if original.file:
                #if change image then delete original file
                original.file.delete()
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            pass
        finally:
            img = PIL.Image.open(obj.file)
            img.thumbnail((500, 500))
            # reset pointer to start at 0 again
            obj.file.open()
            img.save(obj.file)
pre_save.connect(on_save_image, sender = Image)

# delete file in memory
def on_delete_image(sender, **kwargs):
    obj = kwargs['instance']
    if obj.file:
        obj.file.delete()
pre_delete.connect(on_delete_image, sender = Image)
```

Thanks

Comment: wait a second, you remove a file and then trying to open it? :) and second..  it is bad idea to catch all exceptions, if you want to catch something - catch specific things

Comment: I'm using django 1.3 rc1 and what saw is that if you change an image it doesn't delete the original uploaded image that's the reason why I queried and deleted the image manually before uploading the new record. I use obj.file.open to reset the pointer(similar with seek(0)) because when i tried to remove this statement it's not saving the file. I'm still learning django and python that's why I'm not sure if there's a better way to do it. @Jerzyk do have a suggestions on how to simplify the code? Thanks

Comment: as I've told you before use external library https://github.com/sorl/sorl-thumbnail/tree/master/sorl/thumbnail or https://github.com/SmileyChris/easy-thumbnails (last one example:     class Profile(models.Model):
        avatar = ThumbnailerImageField(
            upload_to='avatars',
            resize_source=dict(size=(50, 50), crop='smart'),
        )